# How to match a string which has regexy syntax in it?

Tags: python, regex, pexpect

Suppose I have a string like

```
x = "spam ?and eggs"
```

And I'm trying to match that `"?and"`.  Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
>>> print re.findall(re.escape('?and'), x)
['?and']
```

Is this the correct use case for `re.escape`?  Will it work with any other string literal I'm looking for which may have other types of regex syntax in it?

My use case is with the argument in `pexpect.spawn.expect(pattern)`, where the input pattern can be a string type which gets compiled into a regex.  In some cases what I'm searching for might look like an regex but it is actually a string literal I want to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pexpect, you can use expect_exact() instead of expect() to disable the regex functionality, and it will match exactly the python string you give it.

From the docs:

> **expect_exact**(self, pattern_list, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1)
>   This is similar to expect(), but uses plain string matching instead of
>   compiled regular expressions in 'pattern_list'. The 'pattern_list' may
>   be a string; a list or other sequence of strings; or TIMEOUT and EOF.
>  
>   This call might be faster than expect() for two reasons: string
>   searching is faster than RE matching and it is possible to limit the
>   search to just the end of the input buffer.
> This method is also
>   useful when you don't want to have to worry about escaping regular
>   expression characters that you want to match.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that is exactly the correct use-case for `re.escape` — [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape) says it's "useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it" — though in your first example I think it's a bit simpler to escape the question-mark yourself, using any of these:

```
re.findall(r'\?and', x)          # \? in a raw string literal
re.findall('\\?and', x)          # \? in a non-raw string literal, so, \\?
re.findall('[?]and', x)          # "cheat" by using a character class
```

Comment: Thanks.  Why does escaping it yourself provide a single backslash, but using `re.escape` gives a double?  Is there any significance in this discrepancy?  I will use re.escape because actually I don't know ahead of time what the substring I'm looking for is (it can be anything).

Comment: @wim: Escaping it myself required only a single backslash because I messed up, and should have written either `r'\?and'` (specifying a "raw" string literal) or `'\\?and'` (which means the string containing `\?and`, which in turns means the regex matching a question-mark plus `and`). `re.escape` shows you two backslashes because it produces the string containing `\?and`, and Python's REPL pretty-printing converts that back into a form that could be used in a Python program, namely `'\\?and'`.

Comment: @wim: I've updated my answer to be less wrong (and more complete).

Comment: @ruakh: actually '\?and' works as well as r'\?and' in this case.

Comment: @EduardoIvanec: \*checks\* You're right, `'\?' == r'\?' == '\\?'`. That's good to know, thank you! But somehow it seems better to me to use either `r` or `\\ `, since `\ ` is generally meaningful in string literals.

Comment: @ruakh: yes, I agree it's better to always use raw strings for regexes; I just thought it was interesting (`\+` and `\*` amongst others also work like this).

Comment: `\?` probably works like this: Python tries to interpret it as an escape sequence, but it isn't a valid one, so it leaves it as two separate characters. Indeed, entering `"\?"` at the REPL prints `"\\?"`.

Comment: @Porges: Yes, exactly. Quoth [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-17): "Unlike Standard C, all unrecognized escape sequences are left in the string unchanged, i.e., *the backslash is left in the string*. (This behavior is useful when debugging: if an escape sequence is mistyped, the resulting output is more easily recognized as broken.)" [emphasis in original]

Answer (score 0):

Yup, it looks right to me.  If you're escaping your whole pattern, it's usually a good indication you should be using `find` without regex.

```
x.find('?and')
```

It gives -1 or the position.  So...

```
>>> if x.find('?and') != -1: 
...   print "Match!"
... 
Match!
```

Comment: Yes, I would normally just use `in` keyword like `substring in bigstring`.  But I have to work with pexpect interface.